# Update where datetime is not null - results in null values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I have stored procedure with the following statement.

```
Create table #pokedex
( tier int,
  idNo int,
  name varchar(50),
  lastbattle datetime );

insert into #pokedex (idNO, name, lastbattle) 
(select A.idNO, A.name, B.lastbattle 
from differenttable A -- this table has data pulled from SAP
inner join alternatetable B -- this table has values inserted from SQLBULKCOPY
on A.idNo = B.idNo) 

update #pokedex set tier = 3;

update #pokedex 
set tier = 2
where idNO in (
select idNO from anothertable)
and tier = 3

Update #pokedex
Set tier = 1
where idNo in (
select idNo from #pokedex where lastbattle is not null 
and tier = 2);

select * from #pokedex
order by tier, lastbattle;
```

Results

```
tier    idNO    name    lastbattle
1       001     pidg    null
1       002     ratt    2014-08-22 12:00
1       003     pika    2014-08-22 12:00
2       004     star    null
2       005     muk     null
2       004     mew     null
```

My question: Why does the first row have a `tier = 1` when my update condition was lastbattle not null.

Side info: the insert statement grabs data filled by a `SQLBULKCOPY` command where user's uploaded a large excel file.

Please excuse my love of pokemon as replacement for dummy data.

```
SOLVED - REPLACED UPDATE STATEMENT WITH
UPDATE #pokedex
SET TIER = 1
WHERE LASTBATTLE IS NOT NULL
AND TIER = 2;
```

Comment: You need to show the insert for anyone to be able to figure out what happened during the update (and if that is different from what should have happened). Still, why `update where in ()` instead of just `update where lastbattle is not null`? `idNo` is unique, yes?

Comment: I should have included more information.  The update statement has an additional condition because of my tier conditions.  Tier 3 = no conditions, Tier 2 = condition A.  Tier 1 = condition A & B.

Comment: I've also tried "where lastbattle <> null" -- results in no tier1 results.   "where lastbattle <> ''" -- no diff cause lastbattle is a datetime datatype.

Comment: it seems altering my select statement to update "where lastbattle is not null" did the trick.   For some reason, using the where material in (select ...) caused the problem.  Thanks Aaron.